# select query for select of 2 table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 2 table that i want to select of 2 table where id in order table is equal with order_id in lab table.

order table is

```
id  customer_name  sph    cyl  
1    X             0.25   1.25
2    Y             0.75   2.00
3    Z             1.75   3.25
```

and my lab table is

```
id   order_id   priority   laboratory   laboratory_date 
1       2          1        harry          2021/10/20
2       1          2        hermione       2021/10/18
3       3          3        ron            2021/10/21
```

and I want insert this data into table like below.

```
customer_name    sph   cyl   priority   laboratory    laboratory_date
 X               0.25  1.25   2          hermione      2021/10/18
 Y               0.75  2.00   1          harry         2021/10/20
 Z               1.75  3.25   3          ron           2021/10/21
```

how can I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the `JOIN` keyword in SQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: You know about `INNER JOIN` queries? If not then now is the time to find a tutorial

Comment: i doubt tat this schema will work add another row with hermoine and it will be impossible to connect ids with your data